# How to set automatic height of tableView inside tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an issue which is bothering me for a while. How can I set an automatic height for a tableview which is inside another tableview cell?

So I'm having  **MainTableView** with **3 cells inside it** *(this tableview has automatic height)* and on the **3rd cell I have another tableView inside it** *(let's call it SecondaryTableView which has constraints to its superview)*

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Thing is for the first 2 cells the automatic height it's working.

For the setups of the SecondaryTableView I've tried to do the same but for the cells I've opted for xib files.

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 900
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        registerCells()
    }

    private func registerCells() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MainCategorySectionTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MainCategorySectionTableViewCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AdPerHomePageTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AdPerHomePageTableViewCell")
    }
```

I've attached one more picture of how it looks in the simulator. The green color is the first cell and the orange one the second ( those registered). I've scrolled a little for the first 2 cells to see the difference.

[image: Output]

Might it be that no data is on the cell? But I've put some labels and it looks the same

Comment: which type of content will be in inner cell?

Comment: data parsed from API - > images , and some labels

Comment: And it is also dynamic in height. Right?

Comment: So . The parent is a tableView with 3 cells. ( 1.cell -> collection view which has dynamic height .... 2. cell -> a normal view fixed height ... and now the 3rd. cell I 've included another tableview inside it which will have dynamic cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `intrinsicContentSize` variable of a UITableView.

> Create a subclass for child tableView and override
>   intrinsicContentSize.

[Dynamic row heights of a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667799/dynamic-row-heights-of-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: hi hitest ,i have UITableview inside tableview cell 
i have ui like 
Heading ->subHeading ->Detail when i click on heading it shows subheading when tap on subheading it shows details but when i fast scrolling details are not visible but normally it works fine

Answer (score 2):

You might need a closure at each cells which contain tableView, the closure is invoked as soon as the tableView completed reloading data. 
From you parent tableView, just capture those closures then reload the whole tableView (or corresponding section).

In your main ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.onCompleteReloading = { [weak self] in 
            guard let self = self else { return }
            tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], animationStyle: .none)
        }
        cell.setup()
        return cell
    }
```

In your Cell, define a closure

```
var onCompleteReloading:  (() -> Void)?

func setup() {
    // Do some stuff here
    // Then reload tableView
    self.reloadTableView()
}

func reloadTableView() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self?.onCompleteReloading()
}
```

Comment: could you please give a proper example?

Comment: Hey. I've tried to do it like you said in your answer but unsuccessfully. Same display.

Comment: Please make sure you cell in main controller is ready for dynamic height. Could you share more details about your code?